# What is the "+1 rule" for Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, terminology, dnd-adventurers-league

*This Q&A refers to a rule that was in use for AL from 2015-2020. See [this post announcing its discontinuation](https://yawningportal.dnd.wizards.com/blog/saying-goodbye-to-the-ph1-rule/). This Q&A has therefore been locked against new interactions. Always check your campaign documentation for applicable options and rules.*

---

In many places I see referenced a "+1 rule" for characters legal in Adventurer's League play. What does this mean?

Comment: Related: [Which sourcebooks can be used as the additional resource for AL PHB+1?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165890/which-sourcebooks-can-be-used-as-the-additional-resource-for-al-phb1)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

## Version 1.1 Player's Guides

The “+1 rule” is shorthand for the restriction on being able to use the Player's Handbook *plus one* extra source to build your characters for the Forgotten Realms campaign.

WoTC has [two different campaigns](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack) that utilize different limitations (currently v1.1).

1. Forgotten Realms maintains the "+1" rule (see below)
2. Eberron *does not* and includes additional resources and limitations.

### Forgotten Realms (Waterdeep/Dragon Heist)

From page 2 of the 9.2 version of the Adventurer's League Player Guide (ALPG).

> Forgotten Realms characters can choose race and class options from the *Player’s Handbook* and one other resource—a rule called “PHB+1.” Additional resources include the following products:
>
> - Elemental Evil Player's Companion (EEPC)
> - Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide (SCAG)
> - Volo's Guide to Monsters (VGM)
> - Xanathar's Guide to everything (XGE) [includes Tortle package]
> - Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes (ToF) [Chapters 1-5 only]
> - Locathah Rising (LR)
>
> Additionally, when selecting an additional source, the following variant or optional rules are available when you create your character:
>
> - Variant Human Traits (PHB)
> - Half-elf and Tiefling Variants (SCAG/ToF)
> - Option: Human Languages (SCAG) [This option isn't subject to PHB+1]
> - Blessing of Corellon (ToF) [This option isn't subject to PHB+1]
>
> ***NOTE:*** Races with flight at 1st level, and options from any resource other than those listed above aren’t available without specific campaign documentation (i.e., certs, etc.).

### Eberron (There is no +1 rule per the ALPG linked above.)

From the 1.3 version of the Eberron Campaign Player's Guide (December 2019), which accompanied the *Oracle of War* campaign:

> *Oracle of War* characters can choose race and class options from [see below] only (unless you possess campaign documentation providing additional options).
> You may select the Variant Human Traits option from the Player’s Handbook.
>
> - Player's Handbook (PHB)
> - Xanathar’s Guide to Everything (XGE)
> - Eberron: Rising from the Last War (ERftLW)

The previous guidelines used for the *Embers of the Last War* campaign, released before the publication of ERftLW, substituted the below sources for that book and did not allow any exceptions for use of other material:

> - Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron
> - Volo’s Guide to Monsters (Bugbears, goblins, and hobgoblins only) (VGM)

Comment: **TO THE COMMUNITY**: Please, please just edit in the new stuff as it comes out. The original author does not have the sources or interest in maintaining this answer.