# Does the Adventurers League's "PHB+1" rule also apply to received magical items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league

Yesterday, I was playing an Adventurers League game with a Bugbear character (from *Volo's Guide to Monsters*). I am aware of the Adventurers League's PHB+1 rule, which prevents me from using material from other D&D 5e sourcebooks, like *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*.

However, I received a magical item that comes from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, and I'm wondering if I'm now violating the PHB+1 rule or not.

Does the Adventurers League's "PHB+1" rule also apply to received magical items?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### No.

The [PHB+1 rule](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110848/23970) applies to character creation/advancement, not to items/treasures. It's contained in the "Character Creation" section of the [Adventurers League Player's Guide](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack) and details the options "available to **build** your character." (Emphasis mine.)

(The "advancement" part matters when choosing spells on level-up.)

Note that the ALPG is updated every season--roughly twice per year--so you should always consult the most recent version. When this post was composed the current version was 7.0, for the *Tomb of Annihilation* season.

---

On that note, [AL no longer uses a +1 rule *per se*](https://yawningportal.dnd.wizards.com/blog/saying-goodbye-to-the-ph1-rule/), having replaced it with a broader and setting-dependent rule. The above should still apply, including consulting the most recent applicable ALPG material.

Comment: Answered within 48 seconds. Not bad.

Comment: @SeriousBri Worthy of the title [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: This Q&A is locked for reasons given above. If there are any issues/additions worth addressing/making, please contact a moderator. No, there's no flag option, get creative/chatty :)