# What is the justification (design/mechanic) for the +1 AL Rule?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, designer-reasons

I was thinking out character ideas to maybe someday play in AL, and I came across the [+1 rule](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110848/what-is-the-1-rule-for-adventurers-league?noredirect=1&lq=1).

My question is, *why* is character creation limited in such a way? Other than 'less complexity', what benefit is gained by enforcing only one extra rulebook per character? Was it a design choice (more coherent worlds?) or a mechanical one (less exploitable combos?) or just sort of 'because'?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because designer reasons.

Comment: For more details on designer-reason questions, the problems they’ve had here, the reasons we decided to make them off-topic, and steps you can take to reframe designer-reasons questions to make them on-topic, please see [the Meta discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/4563). Unfortunately, this is one of those questions that probably really *can’t* be reframed to fit the site—and also one of those few designer-reasons questions that actually would have been interesting to see answered well (but almost-certainly would have been answered poorly instead).

Comment: Ethan, you can do a search on Twitter to get Jeremy Crawford's take on some AL topics, and likely find him providing a brief answer to a question like yours.  I had thought we had a related question to point you to here, but I was mistaken.  @Raddu didn't address that point (he was the AL Coordinator for WoTC last year, but has since gotten a new position)

Comment: Consider, also, posing a specific question if you have one, like *How can I create a character like this in light of the +1 rule?*

Comment: @HeyICanChan Sadly I think the Aasimar Favored Soul Sorcerer I had in mind strictly runs into this rule headfirst due to the cross between Xanathar's and Volo's books.

Comment: I'm not a *5e* guy, but there are plenty of 'em around here. It's possible that someone may be able to innovate a solution to your problem anyhow, especially if it's a role-playing opportunity you're after rather than purely mechanical interactions.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77869/room-for-godskook-and-ethan-the-brave  Can't answer, but if you're interested in chatting, here's a chat room.