# Can you play as Warforged in AL?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, warforged

With the release of the [Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/247882/Wayfinders-Guide-to-Eberron-5e) for 5E, can this book be used according to the "[+1 rule](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110848/)" for characters in Adventurers League play? Can you play as a Warforged regardless of the adventure setting?

Comment: @Orgmo — No. DMs running AL games have to follow the rules for AL. House rules are forbidden.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It depends.

See [The D&D Adventurers League Player & DM Pack](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack) which includes player's guides for the *Forgotten Realms* campaign (including the Season 8 *Waterdeep Dragon Heist & Dungeon of the Mad Mage* and Season 4's *Ravenloft* material, among others) and the stand-alone *Eberron* Campaign.

Each has a section on Character Creation which includes "Choose a Race and Class".

Eberron says:

> Your 1st-level character is created using any race and class options in the Player’s Handbook, Xanathar’s Guide to Everything, and **the Wayfinder’s Guide to Eberron**. Bugbears, goblins, and hobgoblins from Volo’s Guide to Monsters are also available for use. No other resources are available—even if other campaign documentation (i.e., certs) otherwise allow it.

The Forgotten Realms section is rather longer, but does not include the Wayfinder’s Guide to Eberron in the list.

It references the +1 rule you mentioned in the question:

> Your 1st-level character is created using any race and class options in the Player’s Handbook plus one other resource from those listed below (the “PHB+1” rule).

This clearly indicates that the +1 rule means "PHB +1 from this list" and not "This list +1 from somewhere else".

(NB: The Realms guide has this rule, but there is no sign of it in the Eberron guide).

---

So you can play a Warforged in the Eberron setting, but not in the Forgotten Realms (plus Ravenloft) setting.

Comment: I think this should be considered part of this question rather than a separate question, so would you mind clarifying whether choosing Warforged for your race in an Eberron campaign also requires using the AL "+1" on the Wayfinder's Guide, or if it's automatically available just by the setting?

Comment: Note: there's now a [Player's Guide](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z8Ws-HPlK-AMUPV4GrR6WqEwSira1ok3/view) (and [DM's Guide](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wwp7PHsnPT74UwNLc0nXjJYW9e31A1wZ/view)) for the *Oracle of War* Eberron campaign, linked from [this post on dndadventurersleague.org](http://dndadventurersleague.org/preparing-for-war-eberron-campaign-preview/). It says the PHB/basic rules and the new *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* book are the only valid sources. (Since *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* has been updated, its versions of character options match those in RftLW.)