# Does the Warforged Resilience racial trait apply to saving throws against poison damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, advantage-and-disadvantage, poison, warforged

The [Warforged Resilience racial trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/warforged#WarforgedTraits) (WGtE, p. 68) states:

> You have advantage on saving throws against being poisoned, and you have resistance to poison damage.

If an attack deals poison damage and includes a saving throw to avoid half damage, but does not inflict the poisoned condition either way, do Warforged have advantage on the saving throw?

For example, the [spider](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/spider)'s bite and the [*cloudkill*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cloudkill) spell would be examples of the type of save I am concerned about.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Does Protection from Poison saves against curse of Scorpion Armor?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123420)

Comment: Note: the name of this warforged racial trait was changed to "Constructed Resilience" in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* and in the updated version of *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*, but the quoted section of the trait was otherwise unchanged.

Comment: Related: [Would Dwarves have advantage on saving throws against the Contagion spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147726/would-dwarves-have-advantage-on-saving-throws-against-the-contagion-spell)

Answer (score 1):

## Against the *Poisoned* condition, yes; against *Poison* damage, no

You're correct about the particulars of the wording of the *Warforged Resilience* feature: because of the precise manner in which it is worded, you would gain advantage on Saving Throws against any feature that afflicts the *Poisoned* condition, but not against Saving Throws against any feature that merely deals *Poison* damage without actually threatening their targets with being poisoned.

## Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron is still considered "Playtest" material

Although holding a higher degree of legitimacy than Playtest material usually gets (compare to Unearthed Arcana), the official stance of Wizards of the Coast is that the *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* book is playtest material, and that this won't change until it is officially released. This is supported by the fact that it's considered ineligible for use in Adventurer's League games ([unless they are specifically set in the Adventurer's League Eberron Campaign Setting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/110849/42386)). A disclaimer in the Introduction of the book also confirms its non-official status:

> Bear in mind: this book presents my current vision of Eberron. This is the world I run at my own table and the way that I've converted its ideas to fifth edition. The game mechanics are usable in your campaign, **but at this time they aren't officially part of the game** and aren't permitted in D&D Adventurer's League events. These mechanics will evolve based on player feedback. This is a living document, and as these concepts are refined, this book will also be updated for free...
>
> —Keith Baker, *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*, pg. 4.

As a result, there's still a chance that this feature will get changed before release.

So while your RAW interpretation of this feature appears to be correct, be aware that this *could* be an oversight or mistake in the wording of the feature, and that the *intent* of the feature is to protect against poison of all kinds, like with the Dwarven equivalent feature.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the WGtE still being playtest? The only reference I can find is this one: https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/1021495845223636994 (which says nothing about it being playtest...just that they can update it more readily as it's a pdf)

Comment: Wayfinders is [eligible for Adventurers league](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110848/what-is-the-1-rule-for-adventurers-league).

Comment: @NautArch Updated with some more concrete information.

Comment: Hmm, so clearly they've made a change to allow it, but didn't update Keith's note at the start. Nice. But either way, I'd put more credence on it actually being used vs the outdated note (which also lays questions on the rest of the note.) But I also think the rest of your answer needs citations to support it. That being said, I don't disagree, and recommend looking to Heroes Feast and Bloodcinder's related link above as well for inspiration :)

Comment: @NautArch What else in my post still needs citations? I'd link directly to the DNDbeyond article (if it exists) but I don't have access to that site right now.

Comment: Well, you haven't really cited anything at all to support your answer. Just that OP is correct. No case has been built, in fact the only {questionnable) case you've built is against one of the source materials.