# Does making a Feral Tiefling in AL require SCAG to be your "+1" book?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, tiefling

Does making a Feral Tiefling in AL require SCAG to be your "+1" book?

My gut is leaning towards yes since those are variants on a PHB race, yes, but the variants themselves are only in that one book.

Comment: Related (and possible duplicate): [What is the “+1 rule” for Adventurers League?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110848/what-is-the-1-rule-for-adventurers-league)

Comment: Doesn't specify if the Variant Tiefling stuff is a +1 or not, though.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes, sadly it does count for the +1 rule.

You can't use Xanathar's subclasses without choosing Xanathar's Guide as your "+1" book, even though the base class is in the PHB. It should be the same with races, too.

And, according to the quote from [NautArch's answer to the linked question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110848/what-is-the-1-rule-for-adventurers-league/110849#110849):

> The variant or optional rules are available when creating your character:
>
> [...]
>
> - Half-Elf and Tiefling Variants (SCAG/ToF)
> - Option: Human Languages (SCAG) [This option isn't subject to PHB+1]

Seeing as it was not specified to deny the rule, it stands to reason the rule still applies.