# Is there any way to get a cantrip from a book outside your PHB+1?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, cantrips

I understand that when you are creating your character in Adventurers League (AL) that you may only use options from the Player's Handbook and one other book (PHB+1).  If I use *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (XGtE) as my +1, is there any way for me to learn a cantrip from the *Sword Coast Adventurer Guide* (SCAG)?

Do any of these options (or something I missed) work in AL?

- Leveling up and being allowed to choose a new cantrip
- Taking a feat, such as Magic Initiate *(PHB p 168)* or Spell Sniper *(PHB p 170)*
- Being a Pact of the Tome Warlock *(PHB 108)* where you can choose cantrips from other classes

While I think I am out of luck (the rule below seems to deny the options above), I am hoping that maybe there is some rule or FAQ answer that I have overlooked along the lines of this (for wizard spells or rituals):

> ### Which Spells Can I Learn?
>
> Spells are a class option; any new spells learned by advancing in a class or by feats are subject to PHB+1.
>   Characters that prepare spells from a spellbook **may copy spells even if those spells aren’t normally found in your character’s PHB+1**.

I don't think the answer will depend on what class we are talking about (since cantrips aren't prepared from a spellbook), but I was specifically thinking about my warlock.  However, I am still very interested to learn whether any class can manage this.

Comment: Related to: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110848/33204

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Not in DDAL play.

Characters can only pick *character advancement* options from PHB+1.

#### Spells in general.

Only **Wizards**, characters with the **Ritual Caster** feat, and Warlocks with the **Book of Ancient Secrets** invocation can learn spells via a method that is not *character advancement*. Once you have the appropriate feature, it is no longer a matter of character advancement, just time and money.

**Ritual Caster** is a bit of a grey area, as the DDAL rule specifies feats. The initial choices certainly have to be from the PHB+1 (because they're granted by the feat directly and the feat is acquired via character advancement), but the ability to add more is not so directly coupled to character advancement.

#### Cantrips, specifically.

As cantrips are not spells that can ever be written in a book, only learned through character advancement, cantrips are also outside of PHB+1.

Comment: <sad trombone> :(