# Which sourcebooks can be used as the additional resource for AL PHB+1?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, books

The [Adventurers League Players Guide](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/AL_PGv90.pdf) for Season 9 explains PHB+1 as follows:

> Forgotten Realms characters can choose race and class options from the
>   Player’s Handbook and one other resource—a rule called “PHB+1.”
>   Additional resources include the following products:
>
> • Elemental Evil Player’s Companion (EEPC)
>
> • Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide (SCAG)
>
> • Volo’s Guide to Monsters (VGM)
>
> • Xanathar’s Guide to Everything (XGE)1
>
> • Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes (ToF)2
>
> • Locathah Rising(LR)*

Is "include" as used here intended to mean "are limited to", or are these resources simply listed as examples of sourcebooks that may be used?

*: Locathah Rising is listed in v. 9.2 of the ALPG that I have on my computer.  I don't remember how I obtained it.  The linked PDF is version 9.0 and does not list this resource.

Comment: Related: "[What is the "+1 rule" for Adventurers League?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110848)"

Comment: As I understand it the newest version of the AL Documents is maintained on the [DMs Guild entry](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack)

Comment: @MivaScott The related question appears to be using old wording that is unambiguous.  A literal interpretation of the Season 9 ALPG rules as written implies that the policy has changed and it is permissible to use resources other than those listed.  As such that answer does not answer this question.

Comment: I believe v9.2 is probably available from dndadventurersleague.org, before [the pack on DMsGuild](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack) is updated. It's here: https://dndadventurersleague.org/al-campaign-rules-updates-january-2020/ (EDIT: The DMsGuild pack has since been updated.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The list is exhaustive

While the wording introducing the list might have some ambiguity, the note below which **excludes some options** is pretty clear:

> ***NOTE:*** Races with flight at 1st level, and options from **any resource other than those listed above aren’t available** without specific campaign documentation (i.e., certs, etc.).
>
> — *AL Players Guide v9.2*

That list is exhaustive as no other source is allowed unless something else explicitly lets you use that option. (Note that the Eberron campaign does *not* use the PHB+1 rule)